# Correct way to convert rows to columns in sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

This is my regular select query:

```
SELECT [category], [price], [company]
FROM [prices] 
INNER JOIN [company] AS [co] ON [co].[company] = [pr].[company]
WHERE [co].[id] IN (1,2,3);
```

The result is:

```
category | price | company 
---------+-------+-------------
 Srv     | 1200  | CoA
 Srv     | 2800  | CoB
 EQ      | 5400  | CoA
 Deduc   | 400   | CoA
 Deduc   | 150   | CoB
```

And I need this result:

```
PriceASrv  | PriceBSrv | PriceAEQ | PriceBEQ | PriceADeduc | PriceBDeduc
-----------+-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------
 1200      | 2800      | 5400     | NULL     | 400         | 150
```

It seems I need twice PIVOT, am I right? does any one have any idea?

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of columns or is it dynamic?

Comment: you don't need to pivot twice, but as you see in the examples below, you need to concatenate the `company` and `category` values.  It also looks like you need all of the `categories` and `companies`, when the result is missing.  Do you have a `company` table with one row per `company` and a `category` table with one row per `category`?

Comment: The SQL language **really** needs to be able to know how many columns and what type at compile time, _before the query actually executes on any data_. If you can't do that, you'll need to either do your pivot in two steps via dynamic sql (where the first step determines the answer to that "how many columns" question) or do your pivot in the client code.

Comment: @SeanLange The categories are fixed but the companies are in dynamic number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not need to pivot twice, but you may need a dynamic query if:

1. There can be more than two companies, OR
2. Your company names can change, OR
3. Your categories can change.

If those three conditions are all false, either of the following queries would work:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Category VARCHAR(10), Price INT, Company CHAR(3));
INSERT @T VALUES
    ('Srv', 1200, 'CoA'),
    ('Srv', 2800, 'CoB'),
    ('EQ', 5400, 'CoA'),
    ('Deduc', 400, 'CoA'),
    ('Deduc', 150, 'CoB');

-- With PIVOT
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CatCom = 'Price' + RIGHT(Company, 1) + Category,
           Price 
    FROM @T) AS T
PIVOT (MAX(Price) FOR CatCom IN ([PriceASrv], [PriceBSrv], [PriceAEQ], [PriceBEQ], [PriceADeduc], [PriceBDeduc])) AS P

-- With CASE aggregation
SELECT PriceASrv = MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Srv' AND Company = 'CoA' THEN Price END),
       PriceBSrv = MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Srv' AND Company = 'CoB' THEN Price END),
       PriceAEQ = MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'EQ' AND Company = 'CoA' THEN Price END),
       PriceBEQ = MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'EQ' AND Company = 'CoB' THEN Price END),
       PriceADeduc = MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Deduc' AND Company = 'CoA' THEN Price END),
       PriceBDeduc = MAX(CASE WHEN Category = 'Deduc' AND Company = 'CoB' THEN Price END)
FROM @T;
```

If any of the three conditions are true, then you may need a dynamic query (which would basically be a modification of either of the above queries to fit your needs).

Answer (score 1):

No you do not need PIVOT twice. See query below. You can convert to dynamic pivot if you don't know the how many companies may be present

```
Select * from 
(
Select 
  [data]='Price' + RIGHT([company],1) +[category] , 
  [price]
FROM [prices] 
INNER JOIN [company] as [co] On [co].[company] = [pr].[company]
WHERE [co].[id] In (1,2,3))src
PIVOT
( 
MAX([price]) FOR [data] in (PriceASrv,PriceBSrv,PriceAEQ,PriceBEQ,PriceADeduc,PriceBDeduc)
)p
```

**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/BQO47023)**

Comment: considering his `NULL` result, I think he'll need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of the `INNER`

Comment: Actually, it's a little more complicated, as he needs all `categories` `cross joined` with all `companies` and then `left outer joined` with related `prices`.

Comment: @Beth I created a demo and reverted back my change. This INNER JOIN will work